Boost::ASIO resolve muliple addresses
I'm having some problems resolving multiple addresses using Boost::ASIO. I can call async_resolve once, get an endpoint, and connect to it without issues. But if I want to call async_resolve again at a later point, async_resolve hangs forever and never calls my event handler.
Is there a way to finish or close the previous async_resolve? Or is it something else?
hostResolver = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver(*internalEventPump->getIoService());
    
hostResolver->async_resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), hostName, portString,
    boost::bind(&DTcpSocket::resolveFinished, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));

...
void DTcpSocket::resolveFinished(const boost::system::error_code &errorCode,
                                 boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator)
{
    endPointIter = iterator;

    if (errorCode)
    {
        errMsg = "Couldn't resolve hostname: " + errorCode.message();
        connectionHandler(errMsg, DA_HOSTNAME_ERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endPointIter;
        cout << endpoint.address() << endl;

        endPointIter++;//we'll try to connect to this endpoint if the first endpoint failed.
        clientSocket->async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(&DTcpSocket::connectFinished, this,
                                                          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}//resolveFinished


You need to show your code. Most likely, the service runs out of work. Consider asio::thread_pool or using asio::work_guard to avoid that. Also, you discard all resolutions except the first one. This is not production quality code. Use asio::async_connect instead.


My example already uses async_connect. 2) I preserve my access to the returned end points in a member variable, endPointerIter. I only require one endpoint to make a connection, but try the rest if the first connection attempt fails. 3) I am periodically invoking poll_one() from my program's event pump, not run(), so I think work_guard can't be the issue? 4) I should mention that this code used to work in boost version 1.55, but hasn't been touched in many years.



No it doesn't. It uses tcp::resolver::async_connect, not asio::async_connect 2) this may be true, but impossible for us to see. Regardless, it's reinventing the wheel with regards to asio::async_connect, so you can avoid the complexity. 3) That's not the case. poll_one() will exit the service just the same, as documented. Also, instead of arguing, you can just see it for yourself in 10 lines of code https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a0857cda243ed69 or indeed, post more relevant code.

